# Unable to send Object while using Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, basichttpbinding

I am trying to send the object through a method api of web service. As service is binded by BasichttpBinding.

```
OneClickOrder OneClick = new OneClickOrder();
OneClick.Mobile = Session["Mobile"].ToString();
OneClick.OrderDetailsList = OrderDetailsList.ToArray();
OneClick.OrderId = 10000;
OneClick.PromoSiteId = PromoSiteId;
OneClick.TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lblafterDiscount.Text);
var OrderResponse = service.OneClickOrder(OneClick);
```

While using service API, I got an SOAP exception

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:order. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 588. 'EndElement' 'order' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element 'Mobile'.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

I didn't get what could be wrong. Is this a problem of Service Side or client side? And i am currently working at client side.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your DataContract class `OneClickOrder` is not same on both server and client.

At client it is different from Server. So, Check your OneClickOrder DataContract Class, Is both are same on server and client.

Comment: Yes Data Contracts are same at both side. So any help?

Comment: If both are same, then the service reference is not updated, updated that and check again.

Comment: I am using Web reference and i updated as well. but didn't know what was goin wrong?